# Maven - What does it exactly do?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Hi would like to ask question about Maven. I have large project in IntelliJ. I know, that IntelliJ can compile the project, bud now i found, that maven can compile the project too? I am asking, because i do not exactly know, what is maven good for. I have thought, that maven is mostly for defining libraries, which are needed for the project to run. Can you please tell me, what other functions maven has and why is good to have it in my project? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

maven is a build system.  It allows you to define parameter needed to build and deploy your project.  So not only does it make your project easy to deploy once it is all set up but it also gives you Portability allowing you to easily deploy you application in many different environments.

To quote the Maven website directly its goals are as follows:

- Making the build process easy
- Providing a uniform build system
- Providing quality project information
- Providing guidelines for best practices development
- Allowing transparent migration to new features

The project [website](https://maven.apache.org/index.html) is also a good place to find answers to these questions and more.  Thankfully the Maven documentation is quite extensive...

https://maven.apache.org/index.html

Comment: Ok, thank you all a lot for explanation! :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use IntelliJ as your build tool. This is not a good solution for a big project, especially if you have a collaborating team working on it.

Maven is a build and dependency management tool. It not only compiles the sources, but also packages resources for the project, builds jar and war packages and does all other things related to different kinds of build process.

See these links to get started:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html
https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/